# OAuth 2 bearer token refresh, avoid chrome/edge popup auth from being displayed

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angular, oauth-2.0

I am on an Angular 6 + .net Web API 2 using OAuth 2.0 token authentication.

When the server returns a 401 (after the token expires) I request a new token using my refresh token. 
This all works well in my local environment but when I deployed it to the development/integration environment, a popup does appear on chrome and edge (not on firefox).

[image]

When I close the popup (without entering any auth data) the authentication process continues and a new authentication token is requested to the server using the refresh token.

How can I prevent this pop up from displaying?

Note: I have read in many post stating that 'another' solution would be not to returning a 401 error or adding a WWW-Authenticate: X-Basic header (maybe I am mixing concepts but as my authentication is a Bearer type, this would not work)

Thank you for your time.

**Edit**

The exact moment when the auth-popup apears is just after the browser performs a preflight (OPTIONS) http request and before performing the 'real' request.

I would like to disable the API authentication for preflight requests. 
Is there any way to accomplish that?